# Is there any way to download or preview a pdf file in mobile applications using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, salesforce-communities

We have been using jsPDF library and plugins to generate, download/ preview pdf files until now. It works smoothly in desktop and mobile browsers. However, in native mobile app neither of `doc.save()` or `doc.output()` works. I get the viewer page with failed to fetch error.

[image]